# How to remove a string of characters after and before a specific character?

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have a file with thousands of lines that start with:

```
>Miriam132_38138    Otu32555|1
```

I need to remove '`Miriam*********`' so that each lines begins with:

```
>Otu32555|1
```

The first string of characters is always a combination of the word 'Miriam' and a set of 7, 8, or 9 characters. I played around with `sed` without much success.

Comment: <stuff><whitespace><stuff>? `awk` is your friend here.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove first "word" from the line you can use something like

```
awk '{print $2}' input.txt
```

assuming you have whitespace between "words"

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the set of 7-9 characters ends with a space, and that `Miriam` is on the line only once:

```
sed 's/\(.*\)Miriam.* /\1/' input.txt
```

The `\(.*\)` part "saves" the pattern matched before `Miriam` and puts it back in with `\1`

Answer (score 0):

Use this,

```
awk '{print $2}' filename > outputfile
```

It should definitely work. It will print the second word of each lines in file and output will be save in the file named "outputfile"

Answer (score 0):

```
sed '/^Miriam/s/[^ ]* *//' <in >out
```

...will do. It will remove from any line which opens with the string *Miriam* only the first sequence of not-space characters followed by the first string of space characters. It will *not* affect any line which does *not* open with that string and it will *not* remove any but the first occurrence of said string.

Answer (score -1):

Use `awk`:

```
awk '{print substr($0, index($0, $2))}' file
```

Removes just the first field, but prints all other fields.

Or `sed`:

```
sed 's/Miriam132_38138 \+//' file
```

If the `>` at the start of the line should be preserved, that removes just the first match.